# Send screen size to server with POST method(node.js) and change html with ejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, screen, ejs

I would like to make responsive web design but I found that I can stretch `html canvas` with css. However, I cannot change pixel amount of `canvas`. So I have decided to get screen size of user and reconstruct with `ejs`. I can get screen size with post method but `ejs` render is not working properly.

Here is node.js code and html code below.

Please help~~!

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(app.router);
//get same information only once

//createServer
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(54885, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:54885');
});

app.get('/',function(request, response){
  fs.readFile('index.html','utf8',function(error,data){
    response.send(data);
  });
});

app.post('/',function(request, response){
  var x = request.param("x");
  var y = request.param("y");
  fs.readFile('canvas.ejs','utf8',function(error,data){
    response.send(ejs.render(data,{
      width:x,
      height:y
    }));
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MildWall canvas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.post('/'+'?x='+$(window).width()+'&y='+$(window).height());
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: EJS doesn't change the current page in the browser, that page has already been sent from the server, and can't be changed other than with javascript in the users browsers at that time. What you're doing is just regular ajax to a regular server, that responds with data.

Comment: then there is no way to make it correct???? any alternative way?? plead help

Comment: This is a simple front-end solution. Your final result should be something like `<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>`, so just use javascript to construct such a div. You can use `canvas.width = $(window).width();` after your page loads. Nothing to do with server code!